# Prevention of Lead conversion as it has a time based action queued

Tags: workflow, process-builder, leads, lead-conversion, time-dependent-workflow

I have a process builder which fires on lead creation.

It creates a time based action, which says that a chatter reminder will be posted after 7 days if no activity on the lead has been made.

So if someone converts the lead in between it should allow it to happen.

My issue here is that, as the time based actions goes into a queue it is not allowing me to convert the lead.

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you are creating time based action based on created date and this time based action is getting queued.

I would suggest you to create a separate datetime field, let's say `Action DateTime` which will initially be populated as `created date + 7 days`.

If any action has taken on the lead then mark this `Action DateTime` as blank.

Your time based action should be defined on the `Action Datetime` and fire the action after `1 hour` on the defined datetime. Also, you should check is `Action Datetime` is not null to fire this action.

This way, your action will not be queued and any user can update the lead.

Comment: We use this internally and it works great.