# Preventing Duplicate Time-Dependent Workflow Actions Without Dequeuing Existing Ones

Tags: time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

I have come across a tricky issue that I can't seem to find a solution for.

We have a workflow rule in place that watches for contacts that meet a certain criteria, and then trigger a set of emails to send out over a span of 6 months. Ideally this should only happen once, so I created a checkbox to be checked once the first email is sent out, and made it equaling false as part of the criteria, so that it doesn't trigger again.

After some time I realized that nothing past the first email was being sent out. That's when I found out that the time-based workflow actions are dequeued if the object is edited to no longer meet the criteria of the original rule.

I'v hit a bit of a brick wall in determining how I can simultaneously prevent duplicate triggers without dequeuing future actions.

I do see that I could have the rule only check on creation of the contact, but the problem with that is that they will sometimes be created with a "Pending" status and later edited to be "Active", so I check for both an "Active" status and that it's either a new record or that it had a previous status of "Pending" on each edit of the contact.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can take this approach https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217858/prevention-of-lead-conversion-as-it-has-a-time-based-action-queued/217863#217863